# Angular reactive form, edit only selected row in list

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to build a dynamic Angular Reactive Form with an array. 
What I want, is to display a table with the static data (not editable) and have an edit / delete icon on each row.
When the user clic on an edit button, the selected line data is display in the dit form bellow the table.

The form have some general data (so for example, a person have a first name and a last name and a list of addresses)

The template:

```
<form [formGroup]="placesForm" class="card mx-4" (submit)="onSubmit()">
    Firstname <input class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" />
    Lastname <input class="form-control" formControlName="lastName" />

    Your addresses :
    <table class="table table-striped" >
      <tr *ngFor="let place of placesForm.get('places').controls; let i=index">
        <td>{{i}}</td>
        <td>{{place.get('street').value}}</td>
        <td>{{place.get('city').value}}</td>
        <td>{{place.get('zipCode').value}}</td>
        <td width="35"><i class="icon-pencil" (click)="editPlace(i)" title="Edit"></i> <i class="icon-trash" (click)="removePlace(i)" title="Delete"></i> </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div *ngIf="selectedPlace">
        <app-address-form [addressForm]="placesForm.get('places').at(selectedPlace)"></app-address-form>
    </div>
</form>
```

The component:

```
export class Step2PlacesComponent implements OnInit {
  private placesForm: FormGroup;
  private selectedPlace = 0;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.placesForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: [null],
      lastName: [null],
      places: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({
          street: [null, Validators.required],
          city: [null, Validators.required],
          zipCode: [null, Validators.pattern(/\d+/)]
        })])
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
  }

  addPlace() {
      places.push(this.fb.group({
          street: [null, Validators.required],
          city: [null, Validators.required],
          zipCode: [null, Validators.pattern(/\d+/)]
        }));
  }

  editPlace(index) {
    this.selectedPlace = index;
  }

  removePlace(index) {
    let places = (<FormArray>this.placesForm.get('places'));
    places.removeAt(index);
    if (this.selectedPlace >= places.controls.length) {
      this.selectedPlace --;
    }
  }
}
```

The `app-address-form` template:

```
<div [formGroup]="addressForm">
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="street" />
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="city" />
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="zipCode" />
</div>
```

And the `app-address-form` component:

```
export class AddressFormComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() addressForm: FormGroup;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

When I clic an edit button, the selectedPlace is updated accordingly but the app-address-form component is not updated an I'm still editing the first row.

Maybe `placesForm.get('places').at(selectedPlace)` is not the right thing to do but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I think you need use viewProviders to make your app-adress-form belong to your form, see .e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53692892/wrapping-angular-reactive-form-component-with-validator/53693760#53693760

Comment: Well, I can't make it work with "dynamic" parent formGroup. The best I have now is displaying the first addressFormGroup but it never update when selectedPlace change... This seems normal: the FormGroupDirective is injected in the constructor and I have'nt set any observer...